# How to extract solution from HHL statevector on qskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, hhl-algorithm

I want to extract the HHL solution from the StateVector.

I am doing this on a $4\times4$ matrix. For a $2$ by $2$ the solution is available in the StateVector $8$, $9$. However for a $4$ by $4$ matrix in which cell do I find the solution. **Is there a way to find out ?**

[image: Here the solution state diagram]

Comment: The solution is stored in qubits where right side of the linear system was at the beginning of the algorithm.